# MySQL: Select nested list from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm working on a game where I have some `images`, where each image has some `keywords` and each keyword have a score.

I want to get all images, and it's keywords (with scores) by `gameId`

**My database structure is like this:**

Games

- id

Image

- id
- gameId
- imageUrl

Keywords

- keyword
- score
- imageId

**I want to get a JSON response that looks like this:**

```
{
    gameId: 1,
    images: [
        {
            imageId: 1,
            keywords: [
                {
                    keyword: "keyword1",
                    score: 1234
                }...
            ]
        }...
    ]
}
```

**My SQL query looks like this:**

```
SELECT g.*, (SELECT i.*, kw.* 
FROM image i LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords kw on kw.imageId=i.id 
where i.gameId = g.id) as images
FROM games g LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on u.id=g.byUser WHERE g.id = 1
```

**But I get this error:**

> ## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What am I doing wrong? Can't I nest an array in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot nest an array in the select list.

Maybe you need this:

```
SELECT g.*, i.*, kw.* 
FROM games g LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on u.id=g.byUser 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN image i on i.gameId = g.id 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN keywords kw on kw.imageId = i.id
WHERE g.id = 1;
```

But there will be extra g.* values in some rows

Comment: Arh okay. I see. So I will have to map the data to a new array, to get the desired structure?

Comment: @Kenneth B You'll receive something like this: Row1 = {gameId: 1, imageId: 1, keyword: "keyword1", score: 1234}; Row2={gameId: 1, imageId: 1, keyword: "keyword2", score: 1234} ...